Microsoft Excel - Adjacent Merged Rows Remain after a copy/paste

I have a Microsoft Excel worksheet that contains a mixture of merged and non-merged cells. The data on my sheet is 8 columns (A through H) by 1200 rows and starts in cell A1 in the upper left corner.
Each 8 column row is essentially a database record that now contains a single row with 8 fields. Some rows have merged cells and some do not have any merged cells. I'd like to add a 9th and 10th column to my sheet. However, when I create the new column, in the "rows" that have merged cells excel will insert the extra number of unmerged cells that match what was originally the number of rows before merging.
I have tried to copy/paste my data block into a new sheet and a new workbook. The merged cells issue persists after copying. In the screenshot example I'd like to copy cells A4::D14 and get eight rows instead of ten rows. I've also tried coping into Microsoft Word table and back, saving as a csv, and saving as an html page.
Is there a way I can get my merged data block into excel without all the "extra" rows in the adjacent columns?
Edit: The new columns do not yet contain data but I'd like to add data in them after they are created.


It might be useful fir you to include some screencaps of what is happening. Side note: merged cells usually produce way more problems that they solve. Consider un-merging them

Are the rows you inserted containing data? Do you have a sample about the table and the rows you're trying to insert?

First unmerge the cells. Just select the entire table and unmerge them.
Next, to get rid of blank rows apply a filter. Once filtered the blank rows will show up at the bottom, and you can easily delete them.
Then turn off the filter.
